# Angular Sort Array Object by value inside object

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, angular6

How get the object by filtering key value inside the object? I have objects below where I need to only pull data which has session_id:23

data = [{
    name: "fist Name",
    session_id : "23",
    login: "date"
  },
  {
    name: "Second Name",
    session_id : "18",
    login: "date"
  },
  {
    name: "Third Name",
    session_id : "23",
    login: "date"
  }];

```
I tried Angular Filter and Map method to filter this out but dosent seem to work for me here.
.pipe(
    map((res) => {
        res => res.filter(res => res.season_id == 23)
        console.log(res);
    })
)

ngOnInit() {
    this._service.getData();
    this._service.updatedPlayer
        .pipe(
            map((res) => {
                res => ress.filter(res => res.season_id == 23)
                console.log(res);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            (playerSession) => {
                this.playerSessionUpdate = playerSession;
            }
        )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing arrays with streams.

You need to use the filter method of Array, not the filter operator of observables.
So if this._service.updatedPlayer contains your observable stream of data, do this:

```
this._service.updatedPlayer.subscribe(data => {
  this.playerSessionUpdate = data.filter(res => res.season_id == 23);
}
```

this.playerSessionUpdate will now contain your filtered data.

Comment: that was my mistake, good point to be noted here array and stream/observables. Thanx for your help Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

your pipe method `map` must return something. So you should actually do

```
 map((res) => {
          return res.filter(res => res.season_id === 23)
     })
```

Comment: this dosent work for me either, this output straing the function like this:  function (ress) { return ress.filter(function (ress) { return ress.season_id == 23; }); }

Comment: but I don't understand where does the 'ress' variables comes from. You have a 'res' and a 'ress' in your example. Is it a typo? please clarify so i can try to help more :D

Comment: Its res only sir, can we filter this it cannot seem to be filtered with this code.